# Location GPS in WebView APP

Tags: ios, iphone, webview, gps, xcode7

I have a doubts acquiring location using the WebView. I created an application with a simple WebView to run on my website. The site has Google Maps showing the location of some places. Mac Safari asks to open GPS to calculate the route since the app WebView does not pull up my location to the map. I've already searched many forums and done many tests however, nothing works.

I use Xcode7.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController , CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var WebView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

         let URL = NSURL(string: "http://inibox.com.br")

         WebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: URL!))
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
         super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
         // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.       
    }
}
```

Comment: someone can help me or give a idea ?